# monthly post timeline for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, timeline

How can i use code from http://astheria.com/this-site/creating-a-timeline-style-archive-page  **([Demo for yearly archive](http://astheria.com/archives))** to show posts on several month instead of year? for example i have 3 posts in jun 2015. and 2 posts in jan 2016 i want to sort posts in month. like below

1. jun 2015

   - post1
   - post2
   - post3
2. jan 2016

   - post4
   - post5

**this is code for yearly archive:**

```html
<?php get_header(); query_posts('posts_per_page=-1');
 $dates_array    = Array();
 $year_array    = Array();
 $i     = 0;
 $prev_post_ts      = null;
 $prev_post_year    = null;
 $distance_multiplier          = 2;
?>

 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  $post_ts    =  strtotime($post->post_date);
  $post_year  =  date( 'Y', $post_ts );

  /* Handle the first year as a special case */
  if ( is_null( $prev_post_year ) ) {
   ?>
   <h3 class="archive_year"><?=$post_year?></h3>
   <ol class="archives_list">
   <?php
  }
  else if ( $prev_post_year != $post_year ) {
   /* Close off the OL */
   ?>
   </ol>
   <?php

   $working_year  =  $prev_post_year;

   /* Print year headings until we reach the post year */
   while ( $working_year > $post_year ) {
    $working_year--;
    ?>
    <h3 class="archive_year"><?=$working_year?></h3>
    <?php
   }

   /* Open a new ordered list */
   ?>
   <ol class="archives_list">
   <?php
  }

  /* Compute difference in days */
  if ( ! is_null( $prev_post_ts ) && $prev_post_year == $post_year ) {
   $dates_diff  =  ( date( 'z', $prev_post_ts ) - date( 'z', $post_ts ) ) * $distance_multiplier;
  }
  else {
   $dates_diff  =  0;
  }
 ?>
  <li style="margin-top:<?=$dates_diff?>px"><span class="date"><?php the_time('F j'); ?><sup><?php the_time('S') ?></sup></span> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php
  /* For subsequent iterations */
  $prev_post_ts    =  $post_ts;
  $prev_post_year  =  $post_year;
 endwhile;

 /* If we've processed at least *one* post, close the ordered list */
 if ( ! is_null( $prev_post_ts ) ) {
  ?>
 </ol>
 <?php } ?>
```

Thanks .
best regards.